# How to blacklist an errpt entry? (so that it will now show up in errpt)

Tags: aix

On an AIX 6.1 OS:

```
LABEL:          CONSOLE
IDENTIFIER:     7F88E76D
```

If we need to blacklist these kind of errpt entries then how can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use errupdate to set an error as non-reportable.  There's an example in the man page for errupdate.

> To modify the log, report, and alert characteristics of entry 99999999 , specify the modify operator = (equal sign) followed by the unique Error ID, and the new characteristics for the entry to be modified:
>
> ```
>         errupdate
>          =99999999:
>          Report = False
>          Log = True
> ```